# How to find the name of the parent class, within a base class in C#?

Tags: c#

I inherit a class from a base class "MyLog".

If I call "Write" within the inherited class, I want it to prefix any messages with the name of the inherited class.

As this application needs to be fast, I need some way of avoiding reflection during normal program operation (reflection during startup is fine).

Here is some code to illustrate the point:

```
class MyClassA : MyLog
{
   w("MyMessage"); // Prints "MyClassA: MyMessage"
}

class MyClassB : MyLog
{
   w("MyMessage"); // Prints "MyClassB: MyMessage"
}

class MyLog
{
  string nameOfInheritedClass;
  MyLog()
  {
    nameOfInheritedClass = ?????????????
  }

  w(string message)
  {       
     Console.Write(nameOfInheritedClass, message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
nameOfInheritedClass = GetType().Name;
```

`GetType()` always returns the *actual* type of the object it's called on.

Answer (score 2):

try to explore

```
this.GetType()
```

properties in the myLog constructor, there you should be able to find type names and other properties of the correct class hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use GetType() to achive this.

```
var parentType = this.GetType().BaseType; //Will return MyLog
```

Where as Jon Skeet pointed out calling `Name` will return the actual type of the object its called on.